# Java print protobuf object of unknown type

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Consider that I have byte array - *byte[]* which represent some kind of serialized protobuf object. Is there any way to print it to output, something like

```
1: 123
2: Jhon
3: Doe
4: 0
```

Where 1 is int field, 2 and 3 are strings and 4 is boolen

*TextFormat.print* requires me to provide concrete *Builder* of protobuf object, which I do not know.

Answer (score 4):

Define a type `EmptyMessage` like:

```
message EmptyMessage {
  // nothing
}
```

Now parse your message as `EmptyMessage`, then call `toString()` on it.

Why does this work? Well, consider that it is backwards-compatible to add fields to a message type. When you add a field, then send a message using that field to an old program that wasn't build with knowledge of the field, then the field is treated as as "unknown field". Unknown fields are printed as number / value pairs. Now, if you start with `EmptyMessage` and add fields, you can obviously get *any other message*. Therefore, all message types are "backwards-compatible" with `EmptyMessage`. Therefore, any message can be parsed as `EmptyMessage` to treat all the fields as unknown fields.

Comment: Any idea how to do it without declaring empty msg in proto ? I mean dynamically at Runtime ?

Comment: @user12384512 Sorry, I don't understand. The same `EmptyMessage` will work for all types, so why would you need to define it "dynamically at runtime"? Why can't you define `EmptyMessage` at the same time as you are writing the other code for this feature? That said, if you really insist on doing it "dynamically at runtime", you can use `DynamicMessage` -- but this will be way more work and have no advantages.

Comment: Caveat: if the protobuf represents an message that contains a sub-message, the sub-message will be stringified as a byte array; in other words, the sub-message will not be unserialized.

Answer (score 1):

if we can make the assumption that the fields are all primitive types (i.e. not sub-messages) then you should be able to loop through all the fields very simply -

```
for(Entry<FieldDescriptor, Object> entry : msg.getAllFields().entrySet())
{
    if(entry.getValue() != null)
        System.out.println(entry.getKey().getName() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
    else
    System.out.println(entry.getKey().toString() + ": null");
}
```

However, I am pretty sure that protobuf objects properly implement the toString() method, so I think you should be able to simply call

```
protoObj.toString()
```

to get a string representation of the protobuf object.
For more info, take a look at:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage.ExtendableMessage#getAllFields%28%29

Comment: I do not have message object as I mentioned above. I have byte array

Comment: using the google protobuf library, you should be able to construct the object with only the byte array. why parse it yourself when there are libraries made to do that already?

Comment: This original question was not about usage of protobuf library, it was about how to print message of unknown type.